# how to iterate over multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

there are many average true range calculations out there, but im trying to figure out how to use a for loop to get the max of the three computations below.

```
high_low= new6["High"]- new6["Low"]
high_close= np.abs(new6["High"]- new6["Adj Close"].shift())
low_close= np.abs(new6["Low"]- new6["Adj Close"].shift())

df= pd.concat([high_low, high_close, low_close], axis=1)
```

df gives me a dataframe of the 3 variables for 50 ETF's, but the first 50 columns are the high_low values for the 50 etfs, and the next 50 columns are the high_close values for the 50 etfs, and the finally 50 columns are the low_close values for those 50 etfs. I want to iterate over all the columns and find the max value of the 3 variables (high_low,high_close,low_close) for each etf and create a column of that max for each etf with the column name to be that etf name. Is it possible to iterate over columns that have the same column name?

below is my code to build a simple DF. please excuse the terrible labeling but since the code is short, I can easily look through it

```
stocks = yf.download(tickers=['SHY', 'IEF', 'ASHR'], period = 
'2y', interval = '1d')

data2= pd.DataFrame(stocks).sort_values('Date', ascending=True)

data3= data2.loc[:,["Adj Close", "High", 
"Low"]].sort_values('Date', ascending=False)

high_low= data3["High"]- data3["Low"]
high_close= np.abs(data3["High"]- data3["Adj Close"].shift())
low_close= np.abs(data3["Low"]- data3["Adj Close"].shift())
ranges= pd.concat([high_low, high_close, low_close], 
axis=1).sort_values('Date', ascending= False)
print(ranges)
[enter image description here][1]
```

as you can see in the image, I get 3 etf's and the different computed range values for each etf. The first 3 columns are the high_low values for the 3 etfs, the next 3 columns are the high_close values for the 3 etfs, and the last 3 columns are the low-Close columns for the 3 same etfs. im trying to figure out if it is possible to look for the max value of the 3 ASHR columns and have a new column created for "Max ASHR" that is that value. Then I would do the same thing for the max value of the 3 SHY columns. with my limited coding knowledge, im trying to figure out if this is possible for large sets of data (I have 50 etfs I want to do it on. just simplied it with 3 etfs for the explanation. All the stuff ive found online for doing something like this only has one etf ticker as an example, which makes it easy since youre just taking the max of the 3 columns for the 1 etf versus having multiple etfs included.

Comment: If you provide sample data, you can find answers to your questions much faster.

Comment: As pointed out by @Clegane, can you provide some sample data, or at least give more details on the shape of your data?  Also, did you really mean 50 columns by indicator, each containing the value for an ETF, or you're actually referring to 3 columns (high_low, high_close, low_close) with 50 rows? If you really meant 50 columns, you want to find out the name of the EFT with the highest value for each of the three indicators? I don't know if this can happen, but what if two or more EFT's end up sharing the highest value? What to do for such cases?

Comment: thanks for the help everyone.  I got it to work by using groupby(level=0, axis=1).max()          after creating a new df with the 3 variables of high_low, high_close, and low_close, the groupby method seemed to work to find the max value

Answer (score 0):

So, my suggestion is kinda of a shot in the dark since I have no idea if I really understood your problem, but you might consider selecting a subset of columns with names partially matching each of your indicators using `pandas.DataFrame.filter` method. Then with this subset of your data, you can call `.idxmax(axis=1)` to retrieve the name of the column with the highest value for each row. It works exactly as the `.max()` method, but instead of returning the maximum value, it returns the column name that contains such value.

Here's the code to do that:

```py
indicators = ["high_low", "high_close", "low_close"]
for indicator in indicators:
    final_df[f"MAX_{indicator}"] = (
        final_df.filter(regex=f".{indicator}")
        .idxmax(axis=1)  # Similar to `.max`, but returns the column name.
        # Just to guarantee that the `.replace` won't fail in some strange corner case.
        .astype(str)
        .str.replace(f"_{indicator}", "")
    )
```

Using the [`yfinance`](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/) package I've generated some sample using stock prices, trying to emulate as best as I could infer, the structure that your real data has.

If you wish to execute the example code, make sure you have [`yfinance`](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/) installed on your machine:

```bash
pip install yfinance
```

**Here's the complete code:**

```py
import yfinance as yahooFinance
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Retrieve the stock data from Yahoo Finance, for each of the following tickers:
tickers = ["AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOG", "META", "CVX"]

# Temporary store each ticker data, to later on concatenate into a single dataframe.
tickers_list = []

# For each value of `tickers`, meaning "AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOG", "META", and so on...
for ticker in tickers:
    # Instantiate the object that holds the stock's data using the ticker value.
    GetStockInformation = yahooFinance.Ticker(ticker)
    # Retrieve historical values of stock for the past 6 months.
    df = GetStockInformation.history(period="6mo").reset_index()

    # Compute the desired indicators.
    high_low = df["High"] - df["Low"]
    high_close = np.abs(df["High"] - df["Close"].shift())
    low_close = np.abs(df["Low"] - df["Close"].shift())

    # Combine the indicators into a single dataframe, adding the sticker as
    # prefix for each column.
    df = pd.concat(
        [high_low, high_close, low_close],
        axis=1,
        keys=[
            f"{ticker}_high_low",
            f"{ticker}_high_close",
            f"{ticker}_low_close",
        ],
    )
    # Store the computed indicators dataframe into the list.
    tickers_list.append(df)

# Combine all the tickers' dataframes into a single dataframe.
# NOTE: the `fillna` method garantees that all values have numbers. This
#       is important later on, as one missing value would result in a `max`
#       with missing values as well.
final_df = pd.concat(tickers_list, axis=1).fillna(0)

# Partial names of the columns that hold the indicators. The actual column names
# start with the ticker as prefix.
# We'll use these partial names alongside `filter` method to select only the
# columns that contain the indicator's label.
indicators = ["high_low", "high_close", "low_close"]
for indicator in indicators:
    final_df[f"MAX_{indicator}"] = (
        final_df.filter(regex=f".{indicator}")
        .idxmax(axis=1)  # Similar to `.max`, but returns the column name.
        # Just to guarantee that the `.replace` won't fail in some strange corner case.
        .astype(str)
        .str.replace(f"_{indicator}", "")
    )
final_df
# Here's how the resulting dataframe looks like:
# ... CVX_high_low  CVX_high_close  CVX_low_close  MAX_high_low  MAX_high_close  MAX_low_close 
# ...     2.634190        0.000000       0.000000  MSFT            AAPL                   AAPL
# ...     4.206852        2.840606       1.366245  MSFT            MSFT                   META
# ...     4.010273        3.931634       0.078639  META             CVX                   MSFT
# ...     3.803855        1.130333       4.934189  MSFT            MSFT                   MSFT
# ...     4.452579        6.998313       2.545734  MSFT             CVX                   MSFT
# ...          ...             ...            ...   ...             ...                    ...
# ...     3.139999        0.369995       3.509995  AAPL            AAPL                   AAPL
# ...     2.649994        0.369995       2.279999  MSFT            META                   MSFT
# ...     4.039993        8.669998       4.630005  MSFT            MSFT                    CVX
# ...     4.250000        6.150009       1.900009  MSFT            MSFT                   MSFT
# ...     4.929993        2.099991       2.830002  MSFT             CVX                   META
```

Below you can find a picture, to better illustrate how the output of the above code looks like:

[image]

Here's also a screenshot, showing what the `pandas.DataFrame.filter` method returns:

[image]

It's important to add the `"."` in front of the indicator's name, to indicate that you want to retrieve every column that ends with `"high_close"`, no matter what characters the column name starts with.